# Using symbols to show values in a boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot, symbols

I have the following dataset:

```
View(Daily_value_traded)

1  6101099210
2  4867827195
3  4733299969
4  7004203242
5  6844117738
6  7358696657
7  4597702008
8  4297631615
9  4559857318
10 4353481097
11 4352241427
12 3158140067
13 4976952949
14 5610945825
15 8330165720
16 7070610560
17 4760429284
18 5809478401
19 5093090544
20 8759159306
21 5976097012
22 7283802104
23 3684133042
24 4225972260
25 4593573946
26 5567090419
27 4360182419
28 5330149706
29 4491976793
30 4176345690
```

Now I would like to create a boxplot and show the following 3 extra values:

```
Day_0 <- 12529037070
Day_before <- 3277596098
Day_after <- 3668502054
```

I found various options on how to add the values as colored dots. However, I would like to use black symbols to show them in a boxplot, like a triangle for Day_0, a square for Day_before and a diamond for Day_after.

Further, I would like to add a legend that explains the symbols.

Could you help me finding a solution?

Edit:

I found the solution by using:

```
stripchart(Day_0, vertical = TRUE, col="black", bg="black", pch = 23, add = TRUE)
stripchart(Day_before, vertical = TRUE, col="black", bg="black", pch = 24, add = TRUE)
stripchart(Day_after, vertical = TRUE, col="black", bg="black", pch = 25, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey, Raver3000, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Specifically,  do you have code to make the boxplot without the extra symbols?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
plot(c(Day_0,Day_before,Day_after), pch= c(17,15,18))
```

In addition, you can look into the documentation under "points" or try out different symbols with

```
plot(0:25,pch=0:25)
```

Legends can be added with "legend".